mokutil certificate not importing
I am trying to use mokutil under Rocky 8.6 hosted on VMware to trust a certificate. I am able to do this on many systems but not others, and I'm having trouble figuring out what the difference is.
$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled

$ mokutil --test-key /tmp/mokutil.der
/tmp/mokutil.der is not enrolled

$ mokutil --import /tmp/mokutil.der
input password: 1234
input password again: 1234

$ mokutil --list-new
# redacted, but cert is definitely present

If we reboot the system, we are taken to the mokutil utility, as expected. We can view and import the certificate here, and the behaviour is identical across all my Rocky and RHEL 8.6 systems. No errors are shown.
However, after booting, we run this again for verification, and on some of my systems, the certificate is enrolled as expected, but on other systems, the certificate is still not enrolled.
# mokutil --test-key /tmp/mokutil.der
/tmp/mokutil.der is not enrolled

I'm not sure where the problem lies, as I am not extremely familiar with secure boot/UEFI/mokutil etc.

Could this be something like the VM's virtual BIOS in vCenter not remembering the certificate? Are the certificates stored in NVRAM?
Or is it something to do with the VM's operating system instead?


I tried deleting the NVRAM file from vCenter, and letting it recreate it, but the same behaviour persists.
